# Ubuntu 16.04.1 Could not get screen information

Tags: display

Since upgrading from 14.x to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS 32-bit, I can not adjust anything in my displays.  I get the following error message : Could not get screen information.  Please assist as I use my second screen ports constantly.

I have a HP 255 laptop with VGA and HDMI outputs.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the ubuntu-desktop with this command? sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

Comment: I have re-installed the desktop and rebooted.  I still have the same error code.