# Ubuntu 17.04 server - Could not get screen information when i open display on gnome-control-center

Tags: 17.04

I tried reinstalling the ubuntu-desktop with this command? `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

I still have the same error code.

i tried lots of things like here

[Ubuntu 16.04.1 Could not get screen information](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814143/ubuntu-16-04-1-could-not-get-screen-information)

i also have this problem

[Icons In System Settings(unity) are Missing Ubuntu Server 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/931235/icons-in-system-settingsunity-are-missing-ubuntu-server-17-04)

```
➜  ~ sudo apt-get clean        
sudo apt-get update                            
sudo apt-get upgrade                  
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release          
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/embrosyn/cinnamon/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Hit:8 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                
Ign:9 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 InRelease
Hit:10 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 Release
Hit:12 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x yakkety InRelease        
Hit:13 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty InRelease     
Hit:14 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease 
Hit:15 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease         
Hit:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease          
Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease [89.2 kB]
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease [89.2 kB]
Fetched 178 kB in 14s (12.4 kB/s)                                   
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  autopilot-desktop autopilot-qt4 autopilot-qt5
  gir1.2-ubuntu-app-launch-3 javascript-common
  libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth libautopilot-gtk libautopilot-qt
  libjs-jquery libjs-underscore libqt4-designer libqt4-help
  libqt4-scripttools libqt4-svg libqt4-test libqtassistantclient4
  libxpathselect1.4v5 mir-utils python3-autopilot
  python3-autopilot-trace python3-autopilot-vis python3-dateutil
  python3-dbus.mainloop.qt python3-decorator python3-evdev
  python3-extras python3-fixtures python3-junitxml
  python3-linecache2 python3-mimeparse python3-pbr python3-pyqt4
  python3-sip python3-subunit python3-testscenarios
  python3-testtools python3-traceback2 python3-tz python3-unittest2
  python3-xlib qttestability-autopilot recordmydesktop
  signon-keyring-extension ubuntu-keyboard-data
  uoa-integration-tests
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
➜  ~ https://askubuntu.com/questions/931235/icons-in-system-settingsunity-are-missing-ubuntu-server-17-04
```

i open gnome control center and konsole shows

```
➜  ~ gnome-control-center

** (gnome-control-center:11990): WARNING **: Ignoring launcher gufw (missing desktop file)

** (gnome-control-center:11990): WARNING **: Ignoring launcher landscape-client-settings (missing desktop file)

** (gnome-control-center:11990): WARNING **: Ignoring launcher ubuntuone-installer (missing desktop file)
```

when i open display on settings

konsole shows

```
(gnome-control-center:11990): display-cc-panel-WARNING **: no sunset data, using 16.00

(gnome-control-center:11990): display-cc-panel-WARNING **: no sunrise data, using 8.00
```

and ui says couldnot get screen information.

All errors are related to each other? should i remıve gnome? i need my settings. gnome settings, for example on mouse settings there is no touchpad opton

i did also here

https://askubuntu.com/a/825034/694849

the id is always changing and there is no gnome

```
➜  ~ ps x|grep control-center
12104 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn control-center
➜  ~ ps x|grep control-center
12110 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn control-center
➜  ~ ps x|grep control-center
12116 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn control-center
➜  ~ ps x|grep control-center
12122 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn control-center
➜  ~ ps x|grep control-center
12128 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn control-center
```

This is my display info

```
 ~ sudo lshw -C video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:126 memory:f2000000-f2ffffff memory:c0000000-dfffffff ioport:e000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:130 memory:f3000000-f3ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:d000(size=128)
```

Comment: First of all, this is not windows and reinstalling rarely fixes problems. Second those warnings are unlikely to be related to your problem. What error code are you trying to fix and what problem so you have ? Also you need to identify both your graphics card and display.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen i added bottom of question. I installd 17.10 server then desktop ubuntu. But system settings are missing when i open settings. You can see here https://askubuntu.com/questions/931235/icons-in-system-settingsunity-are-missing-ubuntu-server-17-04 so i open gnome-control-center to set some settings , but when i click display, it says no info. I want to fix system settings are missing or this could not get screen info and there is no option for disabling touchpad. I use this always to disable 'xinput --disable 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad''. should i renistall ubuntu?

Comment: 17.10 is pre-release so file a bug report and use a supported release.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen i wrote wrong. it is 17.04

Comment: any help please

Comment: Have you had any luck fixing this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I reinstalled ubuntu :(